# How do i know the app is opened on android , conflict by using Intent between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am developing an app with three activities called Activity Ex1, Ex2 and Ex3. The Ex2 and Ex3 activities has `No History = true` flag manifest file.

Ex1 is the main activity

my app flow is `Ex1<->Ex2-->Ex3`

I will set some values in the Ex1 Activities when the app is loaded such as no of counting and setting values for some boolean values.

In the first launch it works correctly. After that I go to Ex1 to Ex2 and come back to Ex1 by using intent (because I have to pass values from Ex2 to Ex1), so that the activity Ex1 values are reset again it causes wrong calculation in my app.

My requirement is whenever I open the app in that time only no of counting to be increased and done other setting values. The counting variables and setting variables should not be changed/modified whenever I am moving between Ex1 to Ex2, Ex2 to Ex1. Those should be effected only when I open the app. How do I do this?

Comment: After you've done your initial counting/calculations save those values as shared preferences. Only recompute those values if they don't currently exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's approach without using shared preferences. I havent tested this, but it should work...

If i understand you correctly you switch between activities `Ex1` and `Ex2` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Ex1.class);
//you are probably putting some data in your intent like this:
intent.putExtra("myData", myData);
startActivity(intent);
```

So when switching to another activity, you can put additional boolean flag saying that your activity was switched from another activity. So when switching to `Ex1`, put put this in your `Ex2` (and possibly all other activities that switch to `Ex1`)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Ex1.class);
intent.putExtra("switched", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, just put following condition in your `Ex1` activity, in place where you are setting data (typically `onCreate` method)

```
//was activity switched to, or did application just start?
//if "switched" key isnt set in your intent, this just returns false
boolean wasActivitySwitchedTo = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("switched");
if(!wasActivitySwitchedTo) {
//application started - **do your value setting here**
...
} else {
//activity was switched to from another activity - **dont do your setting**
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks i got idea from your answer and sorry for delay